# Why am I losing data after I perform a GroupBy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

So this dataset has 2 million records of patients. I've been asked to make every variable dichotomic, and that part is done, but any patient can have multiple records so I have to group them by the patient. When I perform this I lose data; any idea why? This doesn't happen in every field:

[image]

I am adding an image of a sample dataframe to perfom the groupby('npaciente), and then you can see that for each column in valu_ counts it is not returnig anything in the complicacionescronicas column

[image]

Comment: What return `print (g.head())` ?

Comment: Are you aware that `value_counts()` by default does not report `NaN`s?

Comment: print(g.head()) its super large, 169 cols, but for those 2 that i show the 5 top rows are all NaN, and YES i am aware that value_counts doesn't report NaNs by default, but as you can se in the image they are not completly full of NaN and i'm loosing that data upon aggregatioin, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is problem after aggregate `max` you get all `NaN`s, so [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) return empty `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,0,np.nan],
                   'npatience':[np.nan,np.nan,4,5],
                   'C':[1,0,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7]})

print (df)
     A    C  D  npatience
0  1.0  1.0  1        NaN
1  1.0  0.0  3        NaN
2  0.0  NaN  5        4.0
3  NaN  NaN  7        5.0

print (df.A.value_counts())
1.0    2
0.0    1
Name: A, dtype: int64

print (df.C.value_counts())
0.0    1
1.0    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

---

```
g = df.groupby('npatience').max()
print (g)
             A   C  D
npatience            
4.0        0.0 NaN  5
5.0        NaN NaN  7
```

---

```
print (g.C)
npatience
4.0   NaN
5.0   NaN
Name: C, dtype: float64

#check if in column are all values NaNs
print (g.C.isnull().all())
True

print (g.A)
npatience
4.0    0.0
5.0    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64


print (g.C.value_counts())
Series([], Name: C, dtype: int64)

print (g.A.value_counts())
0.0    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (g.C.value_counts(dropna=False))
NaN    2
Name: C, dtype: int64

print (g.A.value_counts(dropna=False))
NaN     1
 0.0    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

`groupby` by default remove `NaN`s rows (cannot groups by NaNs), so it is same as call [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) before `groupby`:

```
g = df.dropna(subset=['npatience'])
print (g)
             A   C  D
npatience            
4.0        0.0 NaN  5
5.0        NaN NaN  7

print (g.C)
2   NaN
3   NaN
Name: C, dtype: float64

#check if in column are all values NaNs
print (g.C.isnull().all())
True
```

And  solution for groupby without remove `NaN`s is replace `NaN`s by value (which is not in `df`) like `1000`:

```
g = df.fillna(1000).groupby('npatience').max()
print (g)
                A       C  D
npatience                   
4.0           0.0  1000.0  5
5.0        1000.0  1000.0  7
1000.0        1.0     1.0  3

print (g.C.value_counts())
1000.0    2
1.0       1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes, after the aggregate function the complicacioinescronicas series is all empty, but I don't know why since before the aggregation it has some values, that is what I'm trying to fix

Comment: Yes, there is problem of data - for NaNs in `npatience` are some data only, another are NaNs. So if groupby, nans rows are removed and get all `NaNs`. groupby do  `df = df.dropna('npatience').groupby('npatience').max()`, so lost data.

Comment: And I have solution , give me some time :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you are losing data when you doing aggregation (`groupby` + `max`) - that's normal.

Demo:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   a  b  c
0  4  1  4
1  4  3  4
2  1  1  0
3  3  3  0
4  4  0  2

In [7]: df.b.value_counts()
Out[7]:
3    2
1    2
0    1
Name: b, dtype: int64

In [8]: df.c.value_counts()
Out[8]:
4    2
0    2
2    1
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

after aggregation:

```
In [9]: g = df.groupby('a').max()

In [10]: g
Out[10]:
   b  c
a
1  1  0
3  3  0
4  3  4

In [11]: g.b.value_counts()
Out[11]:
3    2
1    1
Name: b, dtype: int64

In [12]: g.c.value_counts()
Out[12]:
0    2
4    1
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes, data is supposed to be less but I am loosing data, where there is suppose to be 0 or 1 as in complicacionescronicas from the image, I'm getting NaN, and as far as I know, NaN is not bigger numerically than 0 or 1

Comment: in fact the docs say that when performing aggregations, NaN values are excluded, so the max agg should return something and not an empty series

Comment: @alex, could you please provide a small __reproducible__ data set?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: @alex, please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: i could make it as the post said, but i put an image there that will give u the same result as i get